# YAML and JSON configuration files in Cassandra

Tags: json, cassandra, yaml, cassandra-2.0

I recently started working with Cassandra and am interested in knowing more about 2 files - cassandra_init.json which holds the list of keyspaces and column families and cassandra.yaml which seems to hold a bunch of configuration related fields. Can someone please elaborate why these files are needed and how these files are used/read by cassandra during startup. TIA!

Answer (score 2):

The `cassandra.yaml` file contains the configurable properties of the Cassandra database. At the very least, you would need to configure the following to bring up a minimum viable cluster:

```
cluster_name: your_cluster_name
seed_provider:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          - seeds: "127.0.0.1:7000"
listen_address: private_ip
rpc_address: public_ip
```

There isn't such a thing as `cassandra_init.json` which leads me to suspect that you don't have a standard Cassandra installation and is possibly running a forked distribution. Cheers!